# Track Terraform Plan Output Files in Source Control?

Tags: devops, terraform

The motivation for writing out a terraform plan to a file is kind of vague. So I'm asking if anyone else is clued in as to the motivation behind this. To me it seems like there's a workflow which involves using these plan files, but that workflow isn't clear at all. There's this statement at the end of the documentation for the `plan` command: "Future versions of Terraform will make plan files more secure." So clearly Hashicorp finds a *lot* of value in using these plan files, but why?

Comment: The docs say *"This command is a convenient way to check whether the execution plan for a set of changes matches your expectations without making any changes to real resources or to the state. For example, terraform plan might be run before committing a change to version control, to create confidence that it will behave as expected."* Could you elaborate on what's unclear there?

Comment: @ceejayoz I believe the question is more centered around the generated plan file, rather than the use of `terraform plan` as a test run itself.

Comment: that is correct @ceejayoz. i'm wondering if we are to keep those plan output files in source control, as a way to create an audit trail for what has been done.

Comment: `terraform plan` usage methodology did change somewhat in 0.11 recently by the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying a pre-computed plan file is predictable, whereas running directly `terraform apply` is not.

Imagine you run `terraform plan` and everything looks alright. Now something unpredictable has changed in your infrastructure without you noticing until you run `terraform apply`, which might lead then to different results than what you expected.

With `terraform apply <plan-file>`, any unexpected change between `plan` and `apply` phase would be caught. Especially if you consider building a terraform CI/CD pipeline, using plan files is a great way to add predictability to your automation.

---

**UPDATE**

As mentioned in the comments, an example workflow for automation with plan files can be found in the [official documentation](https://www.terraform.io/guides/running-terraform-in-automation.html#automated-workflow-overview):

> When running Terraform in automation, the focus is usually on the core
>   plan/apply cycle. The main path, then, is the broadly same as for CLI
>   usage:
>
> 1. Initialize the Terraform working directory.
> 2. Produce a plan for changing resources to match the current configuration.
> 3. Have a human operator review that plan, to ensure it is acceptable.
> 4. Apply the changes described by the plan.

---

**FURTHER UPDATE**

Currently, I am still running terraform `0.10.8`, but thanks to the comments of [cm92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4035782/cm92) and [Matt Schuchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5343387/matt-schuchard) I became aware of the following:

Recently terraform `0.11.0` has been released and the [changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0110-november-16-2017) mentions interesting modifications to the behavior of `terraform apply`. By default it will now first generate a plan and wait for confirmation before applying it:

> The command terraform apply with no explicit plan argument is now
>   interactive by default. Specifically, it will show the generated plan
>   and wait for confirmation before applying it, similar to the existing
>   behavior of terraform destroy. The behavior is unchanged when a plan
>   file argument is provided, and the previous behavior can be obtained
>   without a plan file by using the -auto-approve option

Depending on your companies review process, a distinct shareable plan file might still be an interesting option though.

Comment: From my current usage of terraform it seems that with remote state file, running `apply` runs `plan` and then prompts you for confirmation that you want to apply the plan (while keeping the state file locked so that the state does not change until you do). In this way there is no unexpected change between using plan and apply.

Comment: @cm92 some automation schemes / bigger teams might still profit from it as described [here](https://www.terraform.io/guides/running-terraform-in-automation.html#automated-workflow-overview)

Comment: Just thinking about this some more and I wonder if the plan output files could be treated the same as a database migration.